# Optimization of a sql-query with exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, query-optimization

I have a table:

```
+----+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| id | item_id | attr_name | string_value | int_value |
+----+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|  1 |       1 |         1 | prop_str_1   | NULL      |
|  2 |       1 |         2 | prop_str_2   | NULL      |
|  3 |       1 |         3 | NULL         | 2         |
|  4 |       2 |         1 | prop_str_1   | NULL      |
|  5 |       2 |         2 | prop_str_3   | NULL      |
|  6 |       2 |         3 | NULL         | 2         |
|  7 |       3 |         1 | prop_str_4   | NULL      |
|  8 |       3 |         2 | prop_str_2   | NULL      |
|  9 |       3 |         3 | NULL         | 1         |
+----+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

And I want to select item_id with specific values for the attributes. But this is complicated by the fact that the fetching needs to do on several attributes. I've got to do it just using exists:

```
select *
  from item_attribute as attr
  where (name = 1 and string_value = 'prop_str_1')
  and exists
  (select item_id
  from item_attribute
  where item_id = attr.item_id and name = 2 and string_value = 'prop_str_2')
```

But the number of attributes can be increased, and therefore nested queries with exists will increase.
How can I rewrite this query to reduce the nested queries?

UPD:

```
create table item_attribute(
    id int not null,
    item_id int not null,
    attr_name int not null,
    string_value varchar(50),
    int_value int,
    primary key (id)
);

insert into item_attribute values (1, 1, 1, 'prop_str_1', NULL);
insert into item_attribute values (2, 1, 2, 'prop_str_2', NULL);
insert into item_attribute values (3, 1, 3, NULL, 2);
insert into item_attribute values (4, 2, 1, 'prop_str_1', NULL);
insert into item_attribute values (5, 2, 2, 'prop_str_3', NULL);
insert into item_attribute values (6, 2, 3, NULL, 2);
insert into item_attribute values (7, 3, 1, 'prop_str_4', NULL);
insert into item_attribute values (8, 3, 2, 'prop_str_2', NULL);
insert into item_attribute values (9, 3, 3, NULL, 1);
```

Comment: Why are the 2 queries using different table names? are there 2 tables or just one? it would be better to put in the expected output as well so we can asnwer you better

Comment: @TheProvost Oh, it's a mistake! This is the same table. I fixed it.

Comment: the query you had written won't return anything as you have chosen two different attr_name  with different string_value instead of attr_name i think you have to use attr_id to return some result else always both condition will fail as described in you query

Comment: @DharmeshPorwal Not exactly.
The first query (with the condition: attr_name = 1 and string_value = 'prop_str_1') for these data returns 2 lines with id 1 and 4
Given the subquery the result is one row with id 1

Comment: @NickMojarovskiy Your query is working correctly ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you.  It in essence does the same thing... Your first qualifier is that a given attribute name = 1 and string = 'prop_str_1', but then self-joins to attribute table again on same ID but second attribute and string

```
select 
      attr.*
   from 
      item_attribute attr
         JOIN item_attribute attr2
            ON attr.item_id = attr2.item_id
            and attr2.name = 2
            and attr2.string_value = 'prop_str_2'
   where 
          attr.name = 1 
      and string_value = 'prop_str_1'
```

I would also have an index on your table on (name, string_value, item_id) to increase performance of where and join conditions.

Comment: Yes, it will serve! And this request is well extended to the new conditions. Thanks!